# listing all modules from enthought's conopy installation of python packages?

Tags: python, module, importerror, enthought, canopy

I have installed canopy express that comes with many packages to avoid interdependencies.
python works fine on the prompt. I can execute codes and all is well.
but the [link](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/) cites many packages are included in canopy express such as pytest.
but when I try to import pytest, I get `importError`.
Even the `help("modules")` to list all the modules does not work. Anyone using Canopy express can comment if these packages(pytest, curl, distribute etc) are present or not.

```
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Aug  8 2013, 05:37:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help("modules")
no Python documentation found for 'modules'

>>> import pytest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pytest
>>> import distribute
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named distribute
>>> import curl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named curl
>>> import pandas
>>>
```

Comment: What's the reason for using Enthought Canopy? If there is nothing constraining you, I suggest using Homebrew (as I think you are OSX) to install Python and then pip to install those modules you need.

Comment: I used canopy, coz it is supposed to come with 150 packages installed, most of which I want them are in there. secondly, when it seems to avoid interdependencies between libraries. Initally, I was using Mac's python and using pip to install required packages, when I was about to install Networkx, I was getting problems and SO posts suggested to use Canopy to avoid dependency issues and it worked for networkx

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I personally don't like to be tied down to third party distributions if I can help it. Obviously, your problem is that Enthought Python can't find its own packages. I'd suggest clearing out all third party distributions, uninstall all third party Pythons. And reinstall Enthought express. You could try manually setting your PYTHONPATH to where the Enthought site-packages are to see if you can get it to work that way first. When Brew'ing your Python, it installs pip as well. So installing dependencies is a snap, and you get the most up to date modules. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's a bit confusing at times, Canopy Express refers to both the lightweight installer that is available to free users as well as referring to the *set of packages* that is available to these users. By default, the installer does not include all of these but only the main packages, such as numpy, matplotlib, and pandas.

From within Canopy, you should be able to install any of the remaining free packages (pytest, curl, etc.) and, if you've registered for an Enthought account, you'll be able to use this manager to update/delete these packages as well.

See the following articles for more help, including information on command line tools for updating:

- https://support.enthought.com/entries/21600795-Updating-the-Canopy-application-and-its-Python-packages
- https://support.enthought.com/entries/22415022-Using-enpkg-to-update-Canopy-EPD-packages

Comment: Thanks I figured out..but sure this post could be useful for other canopy users